# JW Player : Change current playlist item

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer

I want to set an item in playlist as current playlist item. I checked jwplayer site  http://www.longtailvideo.com/jw-player/javascript/ for documentation but it seems down. I hope somebody here can help me.  Any help and suggestions will be highly appreciable. Thanks.

Comment: It's not down for me, did you check this URL? http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference/

Comment: @w4rumy: Thanks for the response. Am getting *504 - Gateway Timeout* error. May be my office router blocking this site. Let me try with some proxy sites. :)

Comment: The URL you are looking for is http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28851/javascript-api-reference, it is up.